# Creating columns from results in Hive

Tags: postgresql, hive

In hive I'm trying to take the data in a particular column and then split that up into new columns. Then I want to move a column that contains some values and move those into those new columns. If this isn't clear here's what I mean

Table Name: atable

Before:

Name          Date            Label           Value

---

name1         date1           label1           1

---

name2         date2           label2           2

---

name3         date3           label3           3

---

name4         date4           label4           4

---

name5         date5           label5           5

After:

Name          Date            Label1        Label2         Label3       Label4    Label5

---

name1         date1           1

---

name2         date2************************                               2

---

name3         date3***************************************                                          3

---

name4         date4************************************************                                                        4

---

name5         date5************************************************************************                                                                  5

---

Value 1 would be in column label 1. Value 2 would be in column label 2, etc... All the blanks would obviously be null.

Also if this is too hard or a bad idea, I was also thinking of putting them into separate tables. In each of these tables the columns would be name, date, and each of the values from the label column. Under that last column would be the value.

I have tried using dynamic partitioning and joining, but It doesn't seem to work
Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... what's Hive? Link? Which Pg version?

Answer (score 1):

Are you attempting to do a cross-tabulation? If so, see the [PostgreSQL `tablefunc` contrib module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html), which offers the [`crosstab` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html#AEN138683). See the examples there.

To use this you need to be able to call native PostgreSQL functions via whatever Hive is.