# Adding a column which is the result of some formula in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table of values. I want another column which, for example, is thrice the first column plus one (or whatever other formula).

If I write something like this:

```
SELECT item, value, value*3+1 FROM myTable;
```

I get something like this:

```
A    | 1     | 4
B    | 2     | 7
C    | 3     | 10
```

I want to store the third column permanently. Doing this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMN (value*3+1 AS value2 FLOAT);
```

Does not work. However, this does work:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable2 AS SELECT 
    item, value, value*3+1 AS value2 
    FROM myTable;
```

However, I don't want a new table, I want to insert a column into an existing table. I'm thinking I might need to `ADD COLUMN` and then `INSERT OVERWRITE`? Bonus points if your method can use UDFs like avg() or sum(), but I'll take just basic arithmetic for now.

I tried searching and neither [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060605/creating-columns-from-results-in-hive) not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209383/select-columns-from-result-set-of-stored-procedure) answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have a problem maintaining your table if you store calculated columns. This would require a `trigger` operation in a database, which would insert a value into that column after a new row gets inserted. The other way is to have a `view` with the calculated column.

w.r.t Hive, `alter table..` syntax is wrong as a calculation can't be specified here. It should be

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD COLUMNS (value2 FLOAT);
```